# mongo::client::Options::~Options() at options.h:32

Tags: c++, mongodb

I have a strange situation, where, mongodb C++ driver initialize() code crashes with the following seg fault.

```
producer [2560] [cores: 2]  
    Thread [1] 2560 [core: 2] (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault) 
        0x7fffffffdd80  
        ~_Function_base() at functional:2,030 0x448930  
        ~function() at functional:2,174 0x448930    
        mongo::client::Options::~Options() at options.h:32 0x448930 
        main() at main.cpp:17 0x43bf66
```

The corresponding code is as below.

```
#include "config/conf-file-proc.hpp"
#include "producer.hpp"
#include "logger/logger.hpp"

using namespace data::mobility;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Initialize the client
    mongo::client::initialize();      // THIS IS LINE #17 per stack trace.

    std::string producer_conf = "producer.conf";
    data::mobility::Producer producer;

    ConfFileProc cfp2(producer_conf, producer);
    if (cfp2.processConfFile()) {
        producer.getConfig().print();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error in configuration file processing! Exiting..." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

The segment fault is very consistent and I have no idea as to what this is and the reason behind it.

Sometimes, I also see the below warning on the console, but I could not really reproduce this warning.

```
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `mongo::DBClientConnection' value
warning:   found `mongo::getGlobalInitializer()' instead
```

Can someone please provide some clues to fix this?

Comment: I figured out the problem, where the two libraries - my application and mongodb c++ driver code - were not compiled with same compiler flag -std=c++11. After incorporating this change, this error is rectified.